# Run iOS 6.1 Simulator from Xcode and after launch images get a black screen

Tags: ios6, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.6

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 and iOS 6 SDK. When I launch my project at iOS Simulator after Launch Images I can see only black screen. I'm a newcomer in developing. Currently I'm doing app with Tab Bar. Ny Tab Bar do not launch after Images. I have no issues, although Xcode doesn't show it.

Comment: There is what I would call a bug in 4.6.3. Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601802/xcode-4-6-3-can-run-on-device-but-not-on-ipad-iphone-simulators
If you downgrade to 4.6.2 and the problem goes away then that would confirm its a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check whether you have added any view controller in Tab controller.
Next see if you have mentioned your ViewController class properly in the storyboard properties.
Let me know if my answer is not clear

Comment: How I can see I have mentioned my ViewController class in the properties? Sorry for my dullness.

Comment: if you are seeing a bar at bottom & black screen, see in storyboard whether you have connected the tab bar controller to a view controller. If not, control+click on the tab controller & leave the cursor at the view controller.

Comment: to know whether you have added class or not, go to the storyboard & select your view controller(its border will turn blue). Now in utility window,see identity inspector. There first option is to mention Class...(I dont think this would be the problem for black screen)